# How to filter out the entries in a column that are lower than the mean using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset where I'm supposed to remove the values from a column A that are less than the mean of that same column. How can I do this?

There are assert lines where the data frame containing the dataset (df) give:

```
df.shape==(129, 10)
df.values[0].tolist()==[5.4, 0.0, 9.23, 0.0, 1.7, 2.665, 89.2, 23.44, 40.0, 3.2, 24.5, 6.9, 6.290]
```

So does that mean I must include code as well that will answer the .shape part?

Comment: Use `df[df['column A'].lt(df['column A'].mean())`

Comment: @MayankPorwal this works when I add the ```]``` ! However, it doesn't return the same ```.shape``` as in the assert lines. I've edited my post

Comment: Yes, the shape will change. Since you are filtering rows, the number of `rows` in `shape` after my command will be less.

Comment: Does this mean I can't use this? or that there is something else I have to add to come up with the same values in the assert line?

Comment: @kwispychickyjoy - Can you add expected ouput after filter by mean in your data `[5.4, 0.0, 9.23, 0.0, 1.7, 2.665, 89.2, 23.44, 40.0, 3.2, 24.5, 6.9, 6.290]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5.4, 0.0, 9.23, 0.0, 1.7, 2.665, 89.2,
                        23.44, 40.0, 3.2, 24.5, 6.9, 6.290]})
print (df.A.mean())
16.348076923076924

df = df[df.A.lt(df.A.mean())]
print (df)
        A
0   5.400
1   0.000
2   9.230
3   0.000
4   1.700
5   2.665
9   3.200
11  6.900
12  6.290
```

EDIT: If need same size is possible replace not matched values, e.g. by `NaN` in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['A'] = df.A.where(df.A.lt(df.A.mean()))
print (df)
        A
0   5.400
1   0.000
2   9.230
3   0.000
4   1.700
5   2.665
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
9   3.200
10    NaN
11  6.900
12  6.290
```

Or `0`:

```
df['A'] = df.A.where(df.A.lt(df.A.mean()), 0)
print (df)
        A
0   5.400
1   0.000
2   9.230
3   0.000
4   1.700
5   2.665
6   0.000
7   0.000
8   0.000
9   3.200
10  0.000
11  6.900
12  6.290
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but it gives me an assertion error. There's an asserted df.shape and df.values. Sorry, I'll include this in my question

Comment: @kwispychickyjoy - Do you think my solution of comment solution? there missing last `]`